# Give a single suffix/prefix how to add prefix/suffix from a list?

Tags: cmake

I have a cmake file with a statement like:

```
set(SRC_LIST 
    ${SRC_FOLDER}/main.cpp 
    ${SRC_FOLDER}/src1.cpp 
    ${SRC_FOLDER}/src2.cpp)
```

Is there a standard function would produce the same result but with a signature

```
addSuffix(${SRC_FOLDER} main.cpp src1.cpp src2.cpp)
```

There're functionalities for lists and strings but they don't seem to do what I want.

Also it would be useful to know the equivalent of

```
set(SRC_LIST ${SRC_FOLDER_1}/main.cpp ${SRC_FOLDER_2}/main.cpp ${SRC_FOLDER_3}/main.cpp)
```

Do I need to write my own function? if yes how?

Comment: need to try, but how about the prefixes given a suffix? as the title of my question.

Comment: I guess it is not clear what you are asking. So given a string `${SRC_FOLDER}`, you want to add this string as a *suffix* to each of the sources?

Comment: Your example is adding it as a *prefix*...

Comment: @squareskittles I agree, I'm asking the other way around. Fix the suffix and add many prefixes.

Comment: Can you provide an example (in your question post) of what the desired behavior is? The example you provided in your question currently (adding prefixes) is already addressed in the linked question.

Comment: @squareskittles see the update

Comment: You can still use the same solution. Just put your source folders in a list, and use the `TRANSFORM` list function: `list(TRANSFORM SOURCE_DIR_LIST APPEND /main.cpp)`